# Display file without extension as a text file on website

Tags: html

I tried to view a textfile without an extension in the iframe, but Chrome doesn't display it, there is only the "save as" dialog. It works with .txt extension. View-source is useless for me, it must be shown on the website.
I hope you can help me

Comment: How you deal with this depends on the webserver you are using.

Comment: Please explain you issue with example of what you have tried.

Comment: This is working for me, what content do you have in your HTML and text files? See https://i.imgur.com/7uDwesl.png for an example.

Comment: From where did you remove the extension? from the source code? or from the file itself? Please provide us your code.